# Setting secure cookies on Jetty 6 -> 8 upgrade

Tags: cookies, jetty, session-cookies, jetty-8

I've been staring at this for hours and it must be something obviously wrong, but I'm at a loss...

In jetty6 you used to be able to set secure cookies in a web app like this (in the WAR's corresponding $jetty_home/contexts/foo.xml context file):

```
<Get name="sessionHandler">
  <Get name="sessionManager">
    <Set name="secureCookies">true</Set>
  </Get>
</Get>
```

In jetty 8.1.8.v20121106 it looks like the path to do that is (in code):

```
WebAppContext
.getSessionHandler()
.getSessionManager()
.getSessionCookieConfig()
.setSecure(true);
```

So, okay... I do that in my WebApp's context XML configuration like this:

```
  <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="sessionHandler">
      <Get name="sessionManager">
        <Get name="sessionCookieConfig">
          <Set name="secure" type="boolean">true</Set>
        </Get>
      </Get>
    </Get>
```

But jetty fails to come up with this error:

> 2014-02-13 14:20:38.113:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:Config error at true java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager$2.setSecure(boolean)
>   2014-02-13 14:20:38.113:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:Config error at true java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager$2.setSecure(boolean)
>   2014-02-13 14:20:38.114:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:Config error at true java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager$2.setSecure(boolean)
>   2014-02-13 14:20:38.114:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:Config error at true java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager$2.setSecure(boolean)
>   2014-02-13 14:20:38.115:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:Unable to reach node goal: started
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager$2.setSecure(boolean)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.set(XmlConfiguration.java:586)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:391)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.get(XmlConfiguration.java:669)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:397)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.get(XmlConfiguration.java:669)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:397)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.get(XmlConfiguration.java:669)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:397)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:350)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:303)

Anyone see anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there's a bug in Jetty where its XML configuration (sorta like Spring, but pre-dates it) can't call the public setter of an anonymous inner class (which is how the SessionCookieConfig is implemented)

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428157

I'm going to try a work around of adding the secure cookie configuration to our apps' web.xmls like so:

```
<session-config>
 <cookie-config>
  <secure>true</secure>
 </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Thanks to Joakim Erdfelt and Jan Bartel over at the jetty mailing lists for diagnosing this.